# How to properly cast ContextMenuStrip C#

Tags: c#, casting, contextmenustrip

I have been reading for many hours now trying to figure out how to properly cast the Context Menu Strip in Visual Studio 2012 using C#.  I built a little test application to show you what I am trying to accomplish.  Here is a screen shot.

[image]

I have assigned the context menu strip to both controls.  I can return the control that raised the MenuStrip but if  I add another menu item Like in this example (Test) I get "Cant Cast" errors.  Here is the code that I am trying to use.

```
private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    var menu = (ContextMenuStrip)item.Owner;

    MessageBox.Show(menu.SourceControl.Name);
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what type the object really is.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line and check exactly what `sender` is..

Comment: I believe that must be because "Test"'s owner isn't a ContextMenuStrip but rather another MenuItem.

Comment: It should be a `ToolStripItem` which may or may not be a `ToolStripMenuItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the possible already answered question link at the top I was finally able to figure it out.  I believe doing it this way is much cleaner and simpler anyhow.  What I had to do is set an event for the ContextMenuStrip.Opening.  On that event you set the Source Control.  Here is the code.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private PictureBox p;

    private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
    }

    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        p = ((ContextMenuStrip)sender).SourceControl as PictureBox;
    }
}
```